# How do you find waterleafs in terraria iOS?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I can't find a single waterleaf in terraria iOS. I have made many worlds looking for a waterleaf and I can't find a single one. I even have made my own sand biome with the backround and everything, but after several hours a.f.k, there wasn't a single waterleaf. And my world was in hardmode. Are there any tips? Someone please help!

Answer (score 2):

**[Waterleafs](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Waterleaf) should be pretty common. They show up regularly, across several worlds, in my game.**

They appear as small sprouts, with a single leaf, and are much easier to miss then the other plants.

**Try walking through your desert while spamming the attack button.** If you miss them, you should still manage to pick them.

You will notice, in my picture, the farm is filled with water. In an older patch, filling the bed with water would force the plant to drop seeds. This has since been changed, and the plants will only drop seeds if it is raining. Regardless, if they are rare for you, [it might be a good idea to set up a Waterleaf farm.](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide:Gardening)**strong text**

[image]

Comment: Do waterleafs in terraria iOS version only sprout when it's raining?

Answer (score 0):

Waterleafs can be found naturally in sandy areas near a body of water,  most probably a beach. Sometimes,  underground there are small area with sand and water so maybe you can find one but I wouldn't count on that.